# Did Roman Consuls have advisors like senior officials of modern governments (ministers/secretaries) have?

Tags: ancient-rome, political-history

I have begun working on an alternative history story where the Roman Empire has survived to the present/near future. There are a few historical turning points where different decisions were made, each causing a line of events and decisions that contributed to the eventual Collapse of Rome not to happen and instead, different lines of events and decisions that strengthened Rome happened. But this time, I'm interested in the seemingly unimportant issue of who advises the leader?

Clarification following requests in comments: I'm interested in the period from the Early Republic (from establishment onwards) till the Early Empire. You can choose shorter subperiod which you are best familiar with within this frame, but then please specify this.

Comment: there is even an expression for their nobles life paths: "cursus honorum" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursus_honorum  You might look for it and improve your question. Also, each one had a genus  / tribe. Their relatives would also advise them. You also might be more specific: Emperors or republican consuls? Any specific period?

Comment: @Luiz I would assume emperors, at least early, would have followed the system and traditions of the Republic Consuls.

Comment: When? Formally,the Roman government changed little between 300 BC and 200 AD, but in practice it changed enormously. What help the consuls had -- indeed, even what their jobs *were* -- depends on the date?

(My guess is that you're thinking about the Late Republic, basically the century beginning 100 BC, but we need more than a guess to answer!)  N.b., by the late Empire the consulship was more an honorary post than anything, and a huge bureaucracy had developed to run the government. Any modern survival would not look at all like the Republic.

Comment: During the Republic and until the Principate, the Quaestores performed duties similar to ministers under the govern of a consul. But consuls had personal secretaries, like Tiro was to Cicero.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786). Does [WIkipedia:Roman Magistrates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magistrates_of_the_Roman_Empire) answer, or are you looking for cabinet level advisors?  Despite the similarities executive power was exercised quite differently than it is today.  There was less bureaucracy; IIRC prior to Diocletian, the entire empire was supervised by less bureaucrats than currently run an average American county.

Comment: @MarkOlson: Re: "by the late Empire the consulship was more an honorary post than anything" - More specifically, by Caligula's reign the consulship was of so little real significance, it could be done by a [favourite horse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incitatus). Further, it was normal for patrons to second favourite clients to Consuls much as Crassus recommended [Mark Antony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Antony#Service_under_Caesar) to serve under Caesar in Gaul. Finally, research "patron client" in the context of Rome.

Comment: @Pieter No argument that the consulship declined to a primarily ceremonial post fairly early.

Comment: @MCW Thank you for the links; I'll explore them. What I'm looking for is advisors to the consul. Was there an official post, or was it up to each consul who he chose to consult with: friends, relatives, buying a Greek philosopher as a slave?

Comment: Why would they need them? What would a senior advisor do? What policies did consuls/emperors enact?

Comment: @MCW I imagine they would do the same thing the advisors of modern Cabinet members do: advise on policy issues or help navigate minefields of political intrigue.

Comment: I think may be the way to research this.  As far as I understand it, the Consuls/Emperors didn't enact policy, so they would have no need of "expert" advisors.  (as you say, they may have called on ad hoc experts). Might be worth taking a look at the policies issued/votes taken.  My memory is that there are effectively none - they appointed officials and then recessed for the term.